# Microsoft Chart Control X-Axis

Tags: microsoft-chart-controls

I have a Microsoft Chart with a single Series that is defined as ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line. The X-Axis is a DateTime value, and all is working as expected except the last point on the chart. It is overlapping with the end of the chart, and does not look right. See the picture below, how the last point is falling off the chart. In fact, you can see how even the very first point is slightly overlapped by the left border of the chart.

[image: Picture of how the last point is falling off the chart]

My question is: Can anyone suggest a way to correct this? I imagine there may be a way to apply a margin or padding to the X-Axis of the ChartArea, but I can't find it if it's there.

Below is the code that creates the chart:

```
Chart chart = new Chart
{
    Width = w,
    Height = h
};

Series series = new Series("Prices");
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
series.Palette = ChartColorPalette.None;
series.Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#009ad9");
series.BorderWidth = 3;            
series.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
series.MarkerSize = 7;
series.MarkerColor = Color.Salmon;
series.ShadowOffset = 2;
series.XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
series.YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
series.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 8);
chart.Series.Add(series);

ChartArea area = new ChartArea("Area1");
area.BorderColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#e7e8e6");
area.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
area.ShadowOffset = 10;
area.ShadowColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
area.BackColor = Color.White;
area.BackSecondaryColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#f1f1f1");
area.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.TopBottom;
area.Area3DStyle.Rotation = 10;
area.Area3DStyle.Perspective = 10;
area.Area3DStyle.Inclination = 15;
area.Area3DStyle.WallWidth = 0;
area.Area3DStyle.IsClustered = false;
area.AxisY.LineColor = Color.Transparent;
area.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#e7e8e6");
area.AxisX.LineWidth = 1;
area.AxisX.LineColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#666666");
area.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#e7e8e6");
area.AxisX.IsMarginVisible = true;
chart.ChartAreas.Add(area);
```

This queries the data from the database and populates the chart:

```
// Get data for id and add chart area, series, points, etc. to chart
IPriceRepository r = new PriceRepository(Properties.Settings.Default.DcrDb);
var data = r.GetChartData(id);
foreach (var plot in data)
{
    series.Points.AddXY(plot.AuctionEndDate, (double)plot.AuctionHighBid);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is the width of your chart?

Comment: The width is getting passed from an MVC view, so it is dynamic. But in the picture above, it was set to 800px.

Comment: and how you render your chart on view? using DIV or table? I run your code on asp.net web forms and its showing chart correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. My job has fully consumed my time lately. The markup from my view is:
    <div id="chart">
        <img id="graph" src="@Url.Action("GetChart", new { id = Model.CarId, w = 860, h = 300 })" alt="" />
    </div>